# Imagemagic / pdf to jpg / почему плохое качество текста?

Tags: php, pdf, imagemagick

Итак, перевожу сканированный текст из PDF в JPG (размер файла 5 мб) следующим образом:

```
$pdf_file = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/file.pdf';
$im = new Imagick($pdf_file);
$i=0;
foreach($im as $_img) {
   $i++;
   $_img->setResolution(300, 300);
   $_img->setImageFormat('jpeg');
   //$_img->resizeImage(1600, 2400, imagick::FILTER_LANCZOS, 1); 
   $_img->writeImage($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/img/p-'.$i.'.jpg');
}
```

В результате получаю в папку img JPG изображения, но качество текста настолько ужасно, что прочитать невозможно ничего.

Вот пример изображения, хотя оригинал в pdf - отличного качества:

[image]

Пробовал делать ресайз картинки (закомментировано), пробовал ставить `$_img->setResolution(800, 1200);`, результата нет.

Зачем это нужно: нужно сжимать размер пдф-документа средствами PHP, для этого выбрал схему: пдф->jpg / jpg->сжатие / jpg->pdf

Есть идеи?

Comment: Так что посоветуете, уважаемые? Не знаю даже, куда копать?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Разрешение необходимо устанавливать **до** загрузки файла.

Создайте пустой экземпляр `new Imagick()`, установите необходимое вам разрешение с помощью `Imagick::setResolution` и лишь затем грузите ваш PDF с помощью `Imagick::readImage`.

См. [Imagick::setResolution](https://php.net/manual/en/imagick.setresolution.php):

> `Imagick::setResolution()` must be called before loading or creating an image.

Comment: Ничего не помогло =( увы, но спасибо за ответ

Answer (score 1):

Оригинальный текст документа написан **Type3** шрифтом. Каждый символ (глиф) имеет определённое начертание, проще говоря, нарисован. При рендеринге качество отображения букв будет зависеть от размера финальной картинки.

А дайте оригинальный файлик посмотреть, так проще будет понять корень проблемы.

Нашёл какю-то резолюцию ВС, очень похожую на ваш кусок PDF. PDF producer pdfsharp, который отличается низким качеством, но своей бесплатностью. Отрендерил с помощью Apitron.PDF.Rasterizer качество получилось отличное, почти как векторное. [image: введите описание изображения здесь]